# Self Hosted application on Windows Server 2008 R2 only works on localhost

Tags: windows, web-hosting

I'm trying to install a [Go Git Service](http://gogs.io) on a Windows Server 2008. I already installed the aplication and the service under a dedicated user and I can access it from the server (localhost:3000) but I can not access it from another machine.
I can access a website hosted at port 80 on IIS but I'm unable to access the self hosted application.
The firewall is off, I tried to run the command:
`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:3000/gogs user=DOMAIN\user`, disabled IIS, insert the user at the administrators group. Nothing seems to work.

edit: I disabled the IIS and changed the por to 80 and it is working. So it seems I need to open the 3000 port on the server but I'm not sure how, since the firewall is disabled.

EDIT2: The problem was a firewall at the cloud server between the internet and my server.

Comment: I've seen windows firewall still working even when it's disabled. I'd try enabling Windows Firewall and creating an allow rule for that port in it and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I've found the issue. It's a cloud server firewall I didn't know about. I don't know why this is enabled by default..